# FCM Error, SENDER_ID_MISMATCH "PERMISSION_DENIED"

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I get this error when I send a push notification from the backend

> Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 403 Forbidden
> {
> "error": {
> "code": 403,
> "message": "SenderId mismatch",
> "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
> "details": [
> {
> "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
> "errorCode": "SENDER_ID_MISMATCH"
> }
> ]
> }
> }`

```
Message message = Message.builder().setNotification(Notification.builder().setTitle(titulo).setBody(mensaje).build()).setToken(registrationToken).build();

    // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
    // registration token.
    try {
        String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
        logger.info("Firebase response: " + response);
    } catch (FirebaseMessagingException e) {
        logger.error("Error al enviar mensaje de firebase", e);
    }
```

Comment: I have the same issue and tried a few things: new service, changing keys, new project... nothing worked so far...

Comment: I have the same issue too

Comment: @jaketalledo In another thread I commented that my issue started working the following day without any intervention on my side...

Comment: @Esteban I already solve it, it occurs because I have different project Id as I created in project in firebase console first then in google console. So I end up having two different project Id. The step should be create a project first in google console then enable the FCM api, then create a project in firebase console using project id from google console.

Comment: I have the same issue and I cant resolve, can you explain better @jaketalledo?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this problem may be that the google developer account used to create the fcm android application is not the original developer account. Use google play to create an application developer account to create an Fcm android application. It is also invalid to use the authorized google play developer account to create the Fcm android application. According to the fcm official website document, there may be an entry to add other senders, but I did not find it.

The root cause of this problem is: the registration token token does not match the sender id. If you are not the original google developer account, you have to find a way to add an additional "sender".